# Extract transaction data from Aloha POS with SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

Has anyone had any luck extracting transactional data from an Aloha POS system using SSIS?

I am unable to find any resources on the topic.  The end goal is to have this transactional data in a data warehouse for reporting purposes, but I have seen any indication that this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer on another forum.  It seems that you can either access the SQL back-end directly for EOB data, which is updated nightly, or from the front end, set the Aloha software to export a .csv at the end of the day.

Either way, it seems like there is no way to extract real-time data - only nightly.  However, I think that works for me!

Source: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1670815

Answer (score 2):

I integrate to over 50 pos's and the best way I have found for Aloha without paying them 25k for the api is to use the gnditem and gndvoid tables created when grind is done. If all you need is daily data, just query those 2. For real time, I have my app run grind for the date range i want prior to executing the query. For the query I suggest ODBC using Visual Fox Pro VFP driver. You can use dbase driver but much of the sql spec is not supported in it.